# Twitter in Google Calendar

Tags: twitter, google-calendar

I used Twistory until the calendar stopped receiving updates, so I am looking for the correct way to import my tweets into Google Calendar once again.

I tried Yahoo Pipes but it gives me the wrong charset in the calendar.

Comment: if you liked the service, maybe you should try and fix the problem, rather than looking for a new application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [If This Then That](http://ifttt.com).

Use the [Twitter channel](http://ifttt.com/twitter) for your Trigger. Specifically the [New Tweet by You](https://ifttt.com/channels/twitter/triggers/1-new-tweet-by-you) trigger.

For your Action, use the [Quick Add Event](https://ifttt.com/channels/google_calendar/actions/41-quick-add-event) action from the [Google Calendar channel](https://ifttt.com/channels/google_calendar/actions/41-quick-add-event)

You'll want to format your ingredients to something like: `{{CreatedAt}} Tweeted: "{{Text}}"`

Here's a recipe that seems to already be doing what you want: [Measure your Twitter Addiction](https://ifttt.com/recipes/112212-measure-your-twitter-addiction)